# Increasing Bootstrap navbar search form width

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is only the second time I've used stackoverflow so please forgive me if I make any mistakes.

I'm having an issue increasing the width of the default Bootstrap navbar search form. I have tried some of the solutions I've seen on stackoverflow, however nothing seems to work.

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/94zkLh8j/1/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" class="read-more" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Vouchipster</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div style="display:table;" class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for retailers, categories or products">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-green" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the width of the `input` element in your document stylesheet. Use `!important` to override any bootstrap widths. I recommend adding an id to the form for easy selection in css

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/94zkLh8j/2/)

**HTML**

```
...
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" id="navBarSearchForm">
...
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #navBarSearchForm input[type=text]{width:430px !important;}
</style>
```

Comment: @user3383616 You're welcome. Don't forget to mark answers as accepted if you are happy with them.

Comment: this will crash responsive feature. If you use with @media elements, it will be better.